# Why won't this C++ template construction followed by assignment work?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a C++ template that defines a dozen cases for different types.  In this simplified example, I'm trying to understand why I can't construct the template class and then assign to it on the same line:

```
// No problem
PrefShort test1(1);
test1 = 99;

// Also no problem -- although will generate compiler warnings
PrefShort(1) = 99;

// no problem -- will NOT generate compiler warnings
(PrefShort(1)) = 99;

// COMPILE ERROR: "Expected ';' at end of declaration
PrefShort test2(1) = 99;
```

Here's a simplified version of the template in the header file, which inherits from a base class:

```
enum EPrefType
{
    kPrefTypeString,
    kPrefTypeBool,
    kPrefTypeShort
};

class BasePreference
{
public:
    BasePreference(int whichPrefIndex) { fMyPrefIndex = whichPrefIndex; }
    virtual ~BasePreference() { }

protected:
    int fMyPrefIndex;
};


template<class T, EPrefType prefType>
class TPreference : public BasePreference
{
public:
    TPreference(int whichPrefIndex) :  BasePreference(whichPrefIndex) { }

    // assignment FROM T
    TPreference& operator= ( T const& inData )  { fPrefData = inData; return *this; }

private:
    T fPrefData;
};


// PrefShort
typedef TPreference<short int, kPrefTypeShort> PrefShort;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That's just not valid syntax (template or not). Why don't you pass the data to the constructor rather than following construction with an assignment?

Comment: Then why is int x = 99; valid?  Yes, I already DO have a constructor like that.

Comment: `int x{42} = 99;` is not valid.

Comment: Your syntax is trying to initialize the variable in two different ways at the same time. Doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Would you settle for this? `PrefShort test2 = PrefShort(1) = 99;` - it's ugly, hard to read, has no gain, but works.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - Yes -- I was just going to ask why does that syntax work?

Comment: In that case `PrefShort(1)` leaves an lvalue that you can assign to.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - just want to mention: I'm using that syntax because even though the creation of the class goes immediately out of scope, it's designed to update an internal preference data store when it does.  So that's kind of the point.

Comment: It sounds like you need a _function_ not a class.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - good insight -- but what you don't see with my oversimplified example is all the other stuff the class is doing, and the myriad of cases where constructing an object, especially from a template, is super-helpful!

Comment: That does sound like the sort of design that would confuse future readers. Try to follow established norms where feasible.

Comment: Then wouldn't making the constructor into `explicit TPreference(int whichPrefIndex, T const& inData = T{}) : BasePreference(whichPrefIndex), fPrefData(inData) {}` make sense? (or make two separate constructors taking 1 and 2 args resp.)

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- that would just prevent accidental type conversion?  I never use Preference EXCEPT when I typedef each of the 20 specialized types, such as PrefShort.

Comment: The typedef protects nothing if that's what you're asking. Your interface is still open to constructing and then assigning a `T` - so why not support it directly?
If you want to protect it in the base class, you should probably make a subclass where it's allowed and remove `T` from the base. If you don't use `T` in the base scenario, it doesn't need to be there at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is simply no syntax to do that, that's all.

You can have a declarative statement, or you can have some other kind of statement or expression. A declaration simply cannot be merged with operations on the declared entity.

Could we introduce syntax to the language for that? Sure, probably. But it would complicate the rules and not really gain us anything. Code that initializes then immediately assigns should probably just have been properly initialized to begin with.

Your counter-example of `int x = 99` is not fair, because the `=` there is misleading: you're actually just doing a declaration with initialization, *not* an assignment. It's [sort of] equivalent to `int x(99);`, with the `=` syntax essentially kept in for compatibility with C. And you can only have one initializer.

Comment: @SMGreenfield That's a different feature. It's not a declaration. You've got an expression, and the LHS just so happens to involve creation of a temporary. Note that (AFAIK) it's _not_ acceptable if `PrefShort` is a primitive (rules from C)

Comment: For the record, I'm not saying it's _good_ that we have all of these different conditions :P

Answer (score 2):

This is a declaration. Followed by a statement.

```
PrefShort test1(1);      // declaration:   Type VarName{constructor parm}
test1 = 99;              // statement => Expression => Assignment Expression
```

The next two are statements.

```
PrefShort(1) = 99;       // Statement. 
                         // Creating a temporary object by calling a constructor
                         // Then assigns assigning the value 99 to that object
(PrefShort(1)) = 99;     // Same as previous.
```

This is simply invalid syntax:

```
PrefShort test2(1) = 99;  // There is not syntax that allows this.
                          // Its a sort of mangled declaration with extra
                          // stuff on the end.
```

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the template it's just the syntax is wrong,

```
struct A
{
    int _x;
    A(int x)  : _x(x) {}
    A& operator=(int x) { _x = x; return *this; }
};


int main()
{   
    A a(1); // valid 
    a = 3;  // valid 
    A b(2) =2;
}
```

Would repro the same issue (see [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/849c72d902ac9985)).

Comment: It's interesting that the syntax PrefShort(1) = 99; is acceptable.

Comment: @SMGreenfield no variable is declared, only a temporary. it's like `PrefShort something(1); something = 99; /* never use something again */`

Comment: As I mention above, the class is much more complex that the simple example.  These are preferences, and when they go out of scope, they write themselves to the appropriate data store.  When you've got hundreds (or thousands) of preferences, you appreciate being able to have the class handle that stuff.